# Something is wrong. Turtle's screen method "onkey" doesn't work after I used another method - "textinput". Do you have any suggestions?

Tags: python, python-turtle

Something is wrong. Turtle's screen method "onkey" doesn't work after I used another method - "textinput". Do you have any suggestions?

```
screen.onkey(snaky.up,'w') #key listening "
screen.onkey(snaky.down,'s')
screen.onkey(snaky.left,'a')
screen.onkey(snaky.right,'d')
for bodypart in snaky.segments[1:]:
    if snaky.head.distance(bodypart)<10:
        #game_is_on=False
        answer=screen.textinput('RESTART','Do you want to re4start the game?') 
        if answer.lower()==('yes')
            snaky.reset()
            fruit.new_position()
            score.reset_2()
        if answer.lower()==('no'):
            game_is_on=False
            break`
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After using method 'textinput', your program started ignoring interactions with keyboard, so you have to use another method called 'listen()'.
I can show you how you can use it in your program:
when we use if, which determines that the answer is yes, before updating the snake and so on write 'screen.listen()'.

```
answer=screen.textinput('RESTART','Do you want to restart the game?') 
        if answer.lower()==('yes')
            screen.listen()
            snaky.reset()
            fruit.new_position()
            score.reset_2()
        if answer.lower()==('no'):
            game_is_on=False
            break
```

This method makes it possible to interact with the keyboard again!

Comment: `screen.listen` doesn't do anything. Did you mean `screen.listen()`?